# Refactoring else if statement that returns current week from Wednesday

Tags: c#, if-statement

I am quite concerned about whether or not the code in CurrentRentWeek.cs is future-proof, is it good practice to have this many else if statements? If not, what would be the best way to refactor it?

**MainWindow.Xaml.cs**

```
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        // Set current rent week
        var datecheckObject = new CurrentRentWeek();
        CurrentRentWeekTextBlock.Text = datecheckObject.DateCheck(CurrentRentWeekTextBlock.Text);
    }
```

**CurrentRentWeek.cs**

```
    public string DateCheck(string rentWeek)
    {
        if (_today.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Monday)
        {
            _cRentWeekStart = _today.AddDays(-5);
            _cRentWeekEnd = _today.AddDays(2);
            rentWeek = "Current Rent Week: " + _cRentWeekStart.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") + " - " +
                       _cRentWeekEnd.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
        }
        else if (_today.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Tuesday)
        {
            _cRentWeekStart = _today.AddDays(-6);
            _cRentWeekEnd = _today.AddDays(1);
            rentWeek = "Current Rent Week: " + _cRentWeekStart.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") + " - " +
                       _cRentWeekEnd.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
        }
        else if (_today.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Wednesday)
        {
            _cRentWeekStart = _today.AddDays(0);
            _cRentWeekEnd = _today.AddDays(7);
            rentWeek = "Current Rent Week: " + _cRentWeekStart.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") + " - " +
                       _cRentWeekEnd.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
        }
        else if (_today.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Thursday)
        {
            _cRentWeekStart = _today.AddDays(-1);
            _cRentWeekEnd = _today.AddDays(6);
            rentWeek = "Current Rent Week: " + _cRentWeekStart.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") + " - " +
                       _cRentWeekEnd.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
        }
        else if (_today.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Friday)
        {
            _cRentWeekStart = _today.AddDays(-2);
            _cRentWeekEnd = _today.AddDays(5);
            rentWeek = "Current Rent Week: " + _cRentWeekStart.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") + " - " +
                       _cRentWeekEnd.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
        }
        else if (_today.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Saturday)
        {
            _cRentWeekStart = _today.AddDays(-3);
            _cRentWeekEnd = _today.AddDays(4);
            rentWeek = "Current Rent Week: " + _cRentWeekStart.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") + " - " +
                       _cRentWeekEnd.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
        }
        else if (_today.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Sunday)
        {
            _cRentWeekStart = _today.AddDays(-4);
            _cRentWeekEnd = _today.AddDays(3);
            rentWeek = "Current Rent Week: " + _cRentWeekStart.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") + " - " +
                       _cRentWeekEnd.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
        }
        else
        {
            rentWeek = "";
        }
        return rentWeek;
    }
```

Comment: Why do you pass `rentWeek` at all?

Comment: You could factor out the actual assignment to `rentWeek` (either get the two day offset integers and calculate the `AddDays` in one place, or do that in the if/else). You could also look at a `switch` for this as well.

Comment: The only things different inside each block are two integers (effectively one as the difference is always 7). The only thing that determines which block you run is a `DayOfWeek` value. Reason dictates that mapping from `DayofWeek` to integer and slightly tweaking the code will let you replace the branching with straight-line code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can start out with a generalized function to get the start of the week for any give date:

```
public static DateTime StartOfWeek(DateTime date)
{
    while (date.DayOfWeek != DayOfWeek.Wednesday)
        date = date.AddDays(-1);
    return date;
}
```

Then you can simply call that method, add a fixed number of days to get to the end of the week, and create the string for those dates:

```
public string DateCheck()
{
    var startOfWeek = StartOfWeek(_today);
    var endOfWeek = startOfWeek.AddDays(7);
    return string.Format("Current Rent Week: {0} - {1}",
        startOfWeek.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"),
        endOfWeek.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"));
}
```

Comment: thanks for this, I made a few adjustments to the question right before answering. Will you need to update your question as a result? Please let me know.

Comment: +1. Note that with small function with good name it is clear that code is for some very specific locale.

Answer (score 1):

You want that `Wednesday` is the beginning of the week? You can use this:

```
int daysDiff = (int)_today.DayOfWeek - (int)DayOfWeek.Wednesday;
if (daysDiff >= 0)
    _cRentWeekStart = _today.AddDays(-daysDiff);
else
    _cRentWeekStart = _today.AddDays(-(7 + daysDiff));
_cRentWeekEnd = _cRentWeekStart.AddDays(7);
```

This will return the last week's wednesday if today is "less" than wednesday which seems to be desired.

Answer (score 0):

I think a switch statement would be much clearer for your case and give time savings but I doubt thats an issue.

```
switch (_today.DayOfWeek)
            {
                case DayOfWeek.Monday:
                    _cRentWeekStart = _today.AddDays(-5);
                    _cRentWeekEnd = _today.AddDays(2);
                    rentWeek = "Current Rent Week: " + _cRentWeekStart.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") + " - " +_cRentWeekEnd.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");                        
                    break;

                case DayOfWeek.Tuesday:
                    //...
                    break;
                //rest of cases
            }
```